# WhatsApp HTML link

Tags: android, html, whatsapp

iam tried to **connect whatsapp** from html webpage using **UAE PHONE NUMBER**.
the Html link was worked and redirected to WhatsApp. But Showing Error message is..

*"the phone number shared via url is invalid"*

phone number is :- 509626914

code

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=971509626914&text=Can%20I%20know%20more%20about%20your%20service.." target='_blank' class="float">
   <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with my phone numer and is working, you can try to use the minimal address:

Don't forget all rules about the phone number:

+{country_code} {state_code} {number}

In Brazil,
+55 48 9 1234 5678 must be 5548912345678

[https://wa.me/{phone_number}?text={message}](https://wa.me/%7Bphone_number%7D?text=%7Bmessage%7D)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?abid=phonenumber&text=Hello%2C%20World!">Send Message</a>
```

**Solution 2**

```
<a href="intent://send/phonenumber#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">Send Message</a>
```

**Solution 3**

```
<a href="https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=15551234567">Send Message</a>
```

Comment: What is the difference between these 3 solutions?